# Entity Framework: updating an entity based on a sub query/selection

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

We’re receiving messages through a service bus queue, which triggers the execution of some longer running background tasks. Sometimes there are multiple tasks that need to be performed on the same data, but cannot be executed simultaneously as they will create conflicts, that cannot be resolved. But when these tasks are run one after the other (no matter in what order), these conflicts can be resolved.

Therefor I would like to know if the following SQL query can be created using EF.

Using SQL it's possible to update a record based on the existence of some other data during the update:

```
update mytable 
set fieldvalue = @somevalue
where id = @id 
  and not exists (select top 1 * from othertable where <somefilter>)
```

Since this is done using a single transaction, I can assure the update won't be done, when de exists condition fails.

But I can't seem to find something in EF that results in such a SQL statement.

Comment: Yes, it's not really something that fits with the "entity" spirit of EF; execute it as raw?

Comment: @CaiusJard yes, that’s my second option. But I was hoping for some other magic though . If not, I’ll except your comment as answer...

Comment: The `top 1` in the subquery makes no difference at all. Simlpy skip it.

Comment: My essential problem with it is that EF doesn't really update things in that way - you could perhaps query for a `mytable` using the presence of another entitiy in another table, but updating typically is "i have this entity with ID X and when saving to the DB I will update these properties Y where that ID X" - EF knows the ID of what it wants to update, either because it downloaded it and watched you change it or because you fabricated an entity with some ID and told it to save it. The `where not exists` part is "done elsewhere" in the front end logic (i.e. query existence and dont update)

Comment: @jarlh well it does, when you only want to update the entry when something does not exist in the database at the exact time you perform the update action. So when those records exist the update will fail (as required). But as far as I can see the EF update statement are only based on the PK and cannot add extra conditions ofor which an update  can and must fail.

Comment: @CaiusJard in a multi user environment, where users can access and change data at a level where they can both uodate the same data, you want some extra insurance you don’t get undesired conflicts...

Comment: Ahh, then you need to read https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency#:~:text=EF%20Core%20implements%20optimistic%20concurrency,will%20be%20able%20to%20succeed. and have an element of this table control the save (e.g. "another user has confirmed this order since you started editing it" rather than "couldn't update this order because a shipping record put by someone else exists for it") or consider a transactional strategy where you first insert a record to othertable that collides with the PK of any existing record and halt inserting into this table if that other record exists

Comment: ps; jarlh was (correctly) commenting that the `top 1` clause in the EXISTS is redundant and can be removed, but the EXISTS remains. Both these have the same effect: `UPDATE x SET y = z WHERE NOT EXISTS(select null from T)` and `UPDATE x SET y = z WHERE NOT EXISTS(select TOP 1 null from T)`. EXISTS does not care how many rows exist, could be 0, 1, a million.. the DB knows the answer to "exists?" without needing to retrieve even 1 row,so there is no point topping it.

Comment: @CaiusJard thanks for pointing out the concurrency conflict feature of EF. That might come in handy sometime. However, the problem still lies with the actual question. I would like to only update a record when some data in another table exists or not. The use case for having this, is making sure several background processes don’t get executed simultaneously. So the idea is to only update some statusrecord, based on the fact that another status record is not present.

Comment: @jarlh I misread the comment about `top 1` - yes, the the functional outcome is the same, but I though using top 1 would result in better performance as not al records seem te be selected. However it might be I missed something about these kind of exists queries...

Comment: *The use case for having this, is making sure several background processes don’t get executed simultaneously* - so re-engineer your process - pull the record describing the work that is is "NotStarted" state and update it immediately to "Started" - if it gets a concurrency error, it means some other server already started it, give up and pull the next record. It's actually only the same as what you already have - update process id 123 where some log table doesn't have 123 mentioned.. It's just moving the control into "this table". Can still do it with unique keys/insert on othertable too..

Comment: The thing is, these task that need to be processed are received by ServiceBus messages, which are processed in parallel... And those task might edit the same data, so I want to limit the active task which can edit the same data to one.

Comment: Added the use case to the question...